# Duplicate zip entry [97.jar:androidx/versionedparcelable/CustomVersionedParcelable.class]

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I'm facing this problem with android studio 3.0.1.

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForAlaminDebug'. 
>   > java.io.IOException: Can't write [E:\Study\SamarSol\Android\GiftClubCustomer\app\build\intermediates\multi-dex\alamin\debug\componentClasses.jar] (Can't read [E:\Study\SamarSol\Android\GiftClubCustomer\app\build\intermediates\transforms\desugar\alamin\debug\97.jar(;;;;;;**.class)] (Duplicate zip entry [97.jar:androidx/versionedparcelable/CustomVersionedParcelable.class]))

I have tried many solutions but still have an error.

My gradle file is here:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application' 
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.perkssbazaar.member"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    multiDexEnabled true
    manifestPlaceholders = [HOCKEYAPP_APP_ID: "d03e9318b41d4031a783d1cc2b316c81"] //hockey app
}

flavorDimensions "default"

dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}

productFlavors {
    LondonDentalStudio {
        defaultConfig.applicationId "com.perkssbazaar.member.LondonDentalStudio"
        manifestPlaceholders = [
                appIcon: "@mipmap/lds_appicon"
        ]
        resValue "string", "app_name", "London Dental Studio"
    }
    alamin {
        defaultConfig.applicationId "com.perkssbazaar.member.alamin"
        manifestPlaceholders = [
                appIcon: "@mipmap/alamin_appicon"
        ]
        resValue "string", "app_name", "al-amin"
    }
    generic {
        defaultConfig.applicationId "com.perkssbazaar.member"
        manifestPlaceholders = [
                appIcon: "@mipmap/perksslogo"
        ]
        resValue "string", "app_name", "Perkss"
    }
}
buildTypes {
    debug {
        productFlavors.LondonDentalStudio.buildConfigField "String", "flavor", "\"LondonDentalStudio\""
        productFlavors.alamin.buildConfigField "String", "flavor", "\"alamin\""
        productFlavors.generic.buildConfigField "String", "flavor", "\"generic\""
    }
    release {
        productFlavors.LondonDentalStudio.buildConfigField "String", "flavor", "\"LondonDentalStudio\""
        productFlavors.alamin.buildConfigField "String", "flavor", "\"alamin\""
        productFlavors.generic.buildConfigField "String", "flavor", "\"generic\""

        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
compileOptions {
    targetCompatibility 1.8
    sourceCompatibility 1.8
}

}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0'
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:28.0.0'
    compile 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.9.8'
    compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.3.0'
    compile 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.2.0@aar'
    compile 'com.github.moondroid.coverflow:library:1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    compile 'com.cloudrail:cloudrail-si-android:2.6.5'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1'
    //compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.daprlabs.aaron:swipedeck:2.0.6'
    compile 'com.github.jrvansuita:PickImage:2.1.6'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    //compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.4'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:12.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    //compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.12.0'
    compile 'com.daimajia.slider:library:1.1.5@aar'
    //for slide image banner
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    //circular image view
    //compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.12'
    //gif image view
    compile 'com.azoft.carousellayoutmanager:carousel:1.2.1'
    /**For push Notification*/
    compile 'com.microsoft.azure:notification-hubs-android-sdk:0.4@aar'
    compile 'com.microsoft.azure:azure-notifications-handler:1.0.1@aar'
    /**Range seek bar*/
    compile 'com.appyvet:materialrangebar:1.4.1'
    /**For google analytics*/
    //compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.4'
    //compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:10.2.4'
    /*Integration of hockey app*/
    compile 'net.hockeyapp.android:HockeySDK:5.1.1'
    //apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    //implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'

    /* For Payment Stripe Libraries*/
    implementation 'com.stripe:stripe-android:8.1.0'
    implementation "com.stripe:stripe-java:7.10.0"
    implementation 'com.github.extralam:Stripe-Android:1.0.2'

    // glide
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'



}

repositories {
    maven {
        url "http://dl.bintray.com/microsoftazuremobile/SDK"
    }
}
```

** I have added multidex
** Clean project and rebuild
** Clear gradle cache
** Delete .gradle file

But still have an error.

Answer (score 1):

Just Add the following exclude to your build.gradle file.

```
dependencies {
configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'androidx.core', module: 'core'
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have faced a similar issue. I have spent lot of time.

This issue was coming for me because of building app with both androidX(might be transitive dependencies) and google gms libs.

The solution is,either use only androidX or google gms libs.
17+ google gms libs also uses androidX libs internally.
I have downgraded my libs to 16+ and it worked for me.

You can analyze dependencies by executing the command line

```
Mac:    ./gradlew app:dependencies
Windows: /gradlew app:dependencies
```

[image: Changed gms libs version as below]